# Black&white live wires, unidentifed breaker

Tags: electrical, aluminum-wiring

We have 2 wires that were attached to a non functional baseboard heater when we bought our house.We've since removed the heater, but cannot locate the breaker to stop power to the wires. We've gone thru each breaker 1 by 1, and the tester still lights up/beeps. We would like to place an outlet there. Any suggestions on how to proceed on locating which breaker/fuse?

Comment: Beeps? Using a non-contact tester? Non-contact testers can send false-positive responses when circuit wires run close to other hot wires. Additionally if you live in a 120/240v country it is possible you have a 240v heater that is improperly connected to two single pole breakers or one wire crossed up with a different two pole breaker and then two breakers would need to be de-energized

Comment: An additional concern is that sometimes multiple baseboards are often fed by a single circuit, and you would not be able to add a 120v convenience receptacle to a 240v heater circuit.

Comment: Try the other way: turn off all of the circuits and then turn them on one by one, turning each off after testing. If it's live with all of the circuits off there might be a subpanel you haven't located.

Comment: A bit annoying that I can Close all by myself. This is *not* a doorbell, but that is the target I found easily because I remembered my own answer there which is directly applicable here. There are some differences with a doorbell because of a transformer but the basic problem is the same: Determine which breaker powers a circuit.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Closing a question seems extreme when you would need to sort through answers to find a relevant answer. Also split 240v circuits could go undetected.

Comment: Phantom voltage (induced voltage) is a common problem.  Digital multimeters and esp. non contact testers (I think Harp calls them "magic 8 ball testers") are notorious for false readings. Meters are better, but not perfect.  To eliminate induced voltages, a reasonable load (like an incandescent light bulb) needs to be connected to the circuit. Since it's probably a 240 v circuit you'll have to get a 240v light bulb to be safe. Then try EVERY breaker to see when one turns it off. Like NoSparksPlease said, it may involve 2 separate breakers ...that's bad, but might be the case.

Comment: Also, why is the baseboard non-functional? Don't you need it anymore?

Comment: **Binary Search**: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/167014/doorbell-transformer-location-problem/167035#167035

Comment: @NoSparksPlease Agreed re: close. But it would work for 240V as well - just possibly more checks needed. It would be nice if there was an in-between - show clearly that this is a duplicate yet keep it open. Added my answer link as a comment.

Comment: A multimeter is better, be sure to to test each leg to ground, one hot leg caused by a split breaker or one wire interrupted by a single pole breaker would indicate no voltage.

Comment: Does the electrical load center you are looking in have all the breakers for the house? (1)  I have seen a neighborhood built in the early 2000s with all the 2-pole 240 V breakers outside and all the 1-pole 120 V breakers inside. (2) If the OP's house is older than that maybe there is a subpanel with the breakers for the electric bb heaters.

Comment: Yes, it was a no contact tester. We tested on  other sources to see if it was functional.

Comment: The baseboard was here when we bought the house, just a single baseboard in the kitchen addition.

Comment: There is an old fuse box, 4 button fuses, with a breaker box jumped to it. We have mapped all lights, outlets, etc to their fuse or breaker, except this 1.

Comment: Turn off **everything** - i.e., unscrew all fuses, turn all breakers off. Verify that the wires are dead. Then turn on a batch at a time (nominally 1/2 of them) until you find the source.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that as soon as my "assistant" returns from the grocery store.

Comment: Sometimes when a kitchen is remodeled a subpanel is added in or near the kitchen to supply more power than the original wiring. There would be a large 2-pole breaker in the main panel feeding the subpanel.

Answer (score 1):

Connect a noisy appliance to the wires, then start flipping breakers until it goes silent. you're going to need an appliance that's happy with a 240V input.